# Invalid character in identifier when using Python bitwise shift

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to implement a Tausworthe random number generator in python for use in a simulation comparison with some VHDL FPGA code.

[image: Tausworthe Generator]

I have the following in python:

```
#Tausworthe implementation

#define seeds
s0 = 1000
s1 = 2000
s2 = 3000

def Taus():
    b =  (((s0 << 13 )^s0) >>19)
    s0 = (((s0 & ‭4294967294‬)<<12)^b)
    b =  (((s1 << 2) ^ s1) >>25)
    s1 = (((s0 & ‭4294967288‬) << 4)^b)
    b =  (((s2 << 3) ^ s2) >> 11)
    s2 = (((s2 & ‭4294967280‬) << 17)^b)
    return s0 ^ s1 ^ s2
```

I'm getting an error

```
s0 = (((s0 & ‭4294967294‬)<<12)^b)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

I'm unsure as to why. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably copy pasted this code from somewhere. Because there actually is an invalid character with ASCII value of 8237 in there. Try typing out the code from scratch.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami I converted the large constants from hex values using the Microsoft calculator and copy pasted the decimal results. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yup. There are invalid characters before and after each decimal numbers. Simply delete the numbers and go through the trouble of typing them out. That ought to solve your problem.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami That solved it. Thanks! Would you mind adding your suggestion as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: High chance this question will be closed or deleted because it probably won't help other users of the community. But I'll add it as an answer lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually are invalid characters in these lines.

```
...
s0 = (((s0 & ‭4294967294‬)<<12)^b)
...
s1 = (((s0 & ‭4294967288‬) << 4)^b)
...
s2 = (((s2 & ‭4294967280‬) << 17)^b)
...
```

Copy pasting this line in my terminal made it look like this:
[image]

As you can see, there are characters before and after the number that my terminal couldn't recognise.

Simply delete the numbers and type them out instead of copy pasting it.